# Javascript strange if issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

I have two hidden input fields which are changed when there is onchange event This is filled with dynamic info on load

```
<input type="hidden" id="setter" name="{{$value['name']}}" value="{{$field['values'][$value['name']]}}">
```

This one is with empty value and name

```
<input type="hidden" id="old_setter" name="" value="">
```

This is my js code

```
$('.select2').each(function(i, obj) {
  if (!$(obj).data("select2")) {
    $(obj).select2();
  }
}).change(function() {

  var oldSet = false;
  var setter = $("#setter");
  var oldSetter = $("#old_setter");

  if (oldSet != true) {

    oldSetter.val('');
    oldSetter.attr('name', setter.attr('name'));
    setter.val(($(this).val()));
    setter.attr('name', ($(this).attr('id')));
    oldSet = true;

  } else {

    setter.val(($(this).val()));
    setter.attr('name', ($(this).attr('id')));
    oldSet = true;

  }
});
```

The issue is when the hidden setter get the input from visible setter is okay but after that when there is another onchange event on the hidden setter gets updated too, but i want only to update on the first onchange event. Thanks in advance

Comment: `if (oldSet != true)` will always be false. As `var oldSet = false` runs just before it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to define the `oldSet` variable outside of the event (in the global scope), else it will return to `false` on every change the user made and the condition will be always reached:

```
var oldSet = false;

$('.select2').each(function (i, obj) {
  if (!$(obj).data("select2"))
  {
    $(obj).select2();
  }
}).change(function () {
  var setter = $("#setter");
  var oldSetter = $("#old_setter");

  if (oldSet != true) {
    oldSetter.val('');
    oldSetter.attr('name', setter.attr('name'));
    setter.val(($(this).val()));
    setter.attr('name', ($(this).attr('id')));
    oldSet = true;
  }else {
    setter.val(($(this).val()));
    setter.attr('name', ($(this).attr('id')));
    oldSet = true;
  }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Set the on change handler to an empty function after the first event.

```
$('.select2').change(function(){});
```

Comment: I will not test your solution because @Acharki already gave me the solution btw I don't think your solution is connected with the problem in any way. P.S Thank you for your time